# MVC 4 and Jquery how to get download file in bytes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have a Jquery ajax post that calls an Action method.  The action method returns a file as a byte stream.  How can I get the return to the user as a download?  So that it starts downloading?  The file returned could be anything from a txt file to a pdf to an image file

```
 viewAttachmentDetails: function (e) {
        debugger;

        var attachmentId = $(e.target).data("id");
        var model = {};
        model = { attachmentId: attachmentId };
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(model);
        AISApp.Ajax.postJSON(AISApp.Page.getAttachmentURL, jsonData, AISApp.Page.loaderContainer, AISApp.Page.viewAttachmentDetailsComplete);

    },

    viewAttachmentDetailsComplete: function(data)
    {
        debugger;
        window.open(data);  //<<--- what should I do here??

    },
```

my Action method is as follows,

```
public ActionResult GetAttachment(int attachmentId)
        {


            var attachmentDetails = _coesAttachments.GetAttachmentsDetails(new SearchAttachmentsCriteria
            {
                Id = attachmentId
            }).SingleOrDefault();

            if (attachmentDetails != null)
            {

                byte[] fileBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Attachments"].ToString() + @"\" + attachmentDetails.FileName);

                return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, attachmentDetails.OriginalFileName);

            }


            return new EmptyResult();


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Update your `Action` method to return `FileResult`

example:

```
public FileResult Download()
{

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);//replace xml with actual data
            return File(byteArray, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application, "filename");
}
```

Comment: I've just updated my code with my action method... the problem is not in the action method, its how do I send it to the client

Comment: How you're invoking Action method? On hyperlink click?

Comment: AISApp.Ajax.postJSON(AISApp.Page.getAttachmentURL, jsonData, AISApp.Page.loaderContainer, AISApp.Page.viewAttachmentDetailsComplete);